# Accessible Intro to Random Matrix Theory (RMT)

Tags: linear-algebra, random

I read this fascinating article:
http://www.newscientist.com/article/mg20627550.200-enter-the-matrix-the-deep-law-that-shapes-our-reality.html

Unfortunately all the other papers I find googling are just not tangible to me :-(

Could anyone please point me to some material that bridges the gap from this popular science exposition to the hard core papers that seem to pile up in the Net?

Comment: @Qiaochu: Yes, I certainly have. I don't think it is that new - it reaches back half a century by now. But I agree that it lived a life in the shadows.

Comment: I think this may be a good place to look: [Patterns in Eigenvalues: The 70th Josiah Willard Gibbs Lecture](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2003-40-02/S0273-0979-03-00975-3/S0273-0979-03-00975-3.pdf).

Comment: @Tom: I've fixed the link. For reference, google's search results will give you a super-long url with lots of tracking information. It's usually better to click through the link and copy the address from your browser directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like very much and I think that the exposition is very good and clear in the Deift's book:
Orthogonal polynomials and random matrices: a Riemann-Hilbert approach.

Comment: It is useful to have a link handy. Here is one to [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Orthogonal-Polynomials-Random-Matrices-Riemann-Hilbert/dp/0821826956) and [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books/about/Orthogonal_Polynomials_and_Random_Matric.html?id=SBR8yv0LkFgC).

Answer (score 10):

Random matrix theory is a diverse area; and different people prefer different introductions. One question is whether you're mostly interested in mathematical aspect *or* in applications in physics (and other areas). But I can recommend everything below.

**Lecture notes**

[Topics in random matrix theory](http://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/matrix-book.pdf),
*excellent lecture notes by Fields medallist* Terence Tao

[Introduction to the Random Matrix Theory: Gaussian Unitary Ensemble and Beyond](http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0412017),
*lecture notes by* Yan Fyodorov

[Topics in random matrix theory](http://tonic.physics.sunysb.edu/~verbaarschot/lecture/)
*lectures mostly focused on QCD by* Jac Verbaarschot

**Books**

Random Matrices, by Madan Lal Mehta
*canonical on the orthogonal polynomial approach*

An Introduction to Random Matrices, by Greg Anderson, Alice Guionnet and Ofer Zeitouni

**Overview of applications**

The Oxford Handbook of Random Matrix Theory,
Editors: Gernot Akemann, Jinho Baik, Philippe Di Francesco.