# What it means by "asymptotic normality" properties of a random matrix?

Tags: matrices, random

I know that for the case of a random variable and a random vector, one can using (multivariate) density of normal distribution and concepts of convergence to define an asymptotic normality of a random variable (vector).  What about if we have to address this property for a random matrix?  What fields should I read into to know more about this subject?

Answer (score 0):

maybe the normality  means the distribution of the eigenvalues of the matrix.
here are some reference.
[Accessible Intro to Random Matrix Theory (RMT)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3412/accessible-intro-to-random-matrix-theory-rmt/1183972#1183972) 
hope it will help.